# Setup gzip compression at .htaccess for nginx webserver

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, gzip

I would like to know if setting up Gzip Compression for a NGINX web server is the same as setting it up for Apache.

For Apache ([as recommended by GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html)) we add this at `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Refer: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html (Nginx does not support htaccess, so you need to do it the nginx way...)

Comment: You need to modify your nginx.conf file to add gzip support for all those types.  .htaccess fails. been there done that.  google "enable gzip for nginx" and you'll get a ton of tutorials. you need ssh access.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. The first thing you need to do is look for the directive:

`gzip on;`

Comment that out like so:

`#gzip on;`

Now add the following contents above the line you just commented out:

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_min_length 10240;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript 
application/xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```